# AS3: Getting the scale of a Matrix object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, matrix, scale

Most often, questions are asked about how to scale a DisplayObject, and the answer is usually to use a Matrix.

My question is, how to you GET the scale of a Matrix (scaleX and scaleY)?

There's a Matrix.scale method to set the scaleX and scaleY, but it doesn't return a value, and no other properties exist to read it back.

The reason I ask, I'm using object burried deep down into a Display list, and each may be transformed. So I use the child object's  sprite.transform.concatenatedMatrix getter, but am stuck at this point on how to read the scale from it.

Any Math Wiz in the house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, a reliable way to isolate the scaling component in a matrix is to use the matrix in question to transform the unit vectors along the axes, and then measure the length of the resulting vectors.

For instance, given the `transform` from a DisplayObject, and using the Matrix3D, the `scaleX` would be obtained as follows:

```
transform.matrix3D.deltaTransformVector(Vector3D.X_AXIS).length
```

Or, if you use the concatenated 2D Matrix, the `scaleY` would be:

```
transform.concatenatedMatrix.deltaTransformPoint(new Point(0,1)).length
```

Note that the `deltaTransform*` functions ignore the translation effects of the matrices, which have no effect on the scaling.

Comment: Interesting, I gave this a shot (as a 2D Matrix) and it certainly gives the scale values, but when compared with the actual value of the DisplayObject's scaleX and scaleY, they usually vary - but only very slightly (like 4 to 5 positions after the decimal point). Great answer nonetheless! Thanks

Comment: Worth noting: I've tried to deltaTransformPoint( new Point(1,1) ) thinking the resulting x & y would be the scale values. But this unfortunatly doesn't give accurate values. Each axis has to be processed independantly. I'm no genius with Matrices, but whatever! This works for me :)

Comment: The discrepancy in the values might be introduced by the calculation of the length, or from the concatenation of the matrix, which means that the scaling on all ancestors is applied to the object, in addition to any scaleX/Y you might add to it directly.  On the (1,1) transform: the length of the transformed Point would yield sqrt(2)*(scale factor along the Y=X Axis).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the x and y scales of a matrix even when it's rotated.

Here's the code:

```
public static function getScaleX(m:Matrix):Number
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(m.a + m.b, 2));
}

public static function getScaleY(m:Matrix):Number
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(m.c + m.d, 2));
}
```

Explanation:

I've found that it's easier to think of `A B C D` as points that define the x and y axes in the transformed coordinate space. `A, B` is the position of the first point of the transformed x axis (an identity matrix has these as `1, 0`, which will not transform), and `C, D` is the position of the first point of the transformed y axis (identity values of `0, 1`).

If we have a matrix that will scale the x axis by 2 then `A, B` will be `2, 0`. The rest of the points on x axis will be this same distance away from the last (so 2 points away from the last).

If we have a matrix that will rotate 90 degrees clockwise then `A, B` will be `0, 1` (pointing the x axis along the positive side of the y axis) and `C, D` will be `-1, 0` (pointing the y axis down the negative side of the x axis).

The scale of the x axis is the distance to the first point. In the scenarios that I've mentioned the scale is easy to find. In the previous example `A, B` is `0, 1` so the scale is 1. If rotation is not on at a 90 degree increment then you can find the length of the line segment from `0, 0` to `A, B` by using the Pythagorean theorem: sqrt(a^2 + b^2) = c. This is what my code is doing.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you have access to the matrix object's `a` and `d` public properties, which represent the scaling of the x-axis and y-axis respectively:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.display.Shape;

//Class
public class Test extends Sprite
    {
    //Constructor
    public function Test()
        {       
        var sh:Shape = new Shape();
        sh.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
        sh.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        sh.graphics.endFill();

        var scaleMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.scale(4, 6);

        sh.transform.matrix = scaleMatrix;

        addChild(sh);

        trace("Matrix X Scale: " + scaleMatrix.a, "\nMatrix Y Scale: " + scaleMatrix.d);
        }
    }
}

// Matrix X Scale: 4 
// Matrix Y Scale: 6
```

Comment: forgot to mention that a and d also represent rotation so my above code will only work if you are only scaling.

Comment: Yeah rotation is important to keep in consideration in my case, some objects will be turned 90degrees, and in general it's good to have an all-in-one solution that can solve for any scenarios (any scales, rotations or skews too). Thanks though!