# how to get scaled height and width?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a `s:Group` with few fixed size components in it, these are lets suppose `200x300`, `300x150` etc
Now if i resize `s:Group` with `resizeMode=Scale,  (scale down)`. and try to read the scaled down size of these child components but they still has the same old height and width.

how can i get width and height after scaling down the parent group?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey there :]
At first i thought it would be an easy task to get the width and height. But when i tried it, none of explicitWidth and measuredWidth worked, when resizeMode is set to "scale" of the s:Group.

So i found a way but i'm not sure if it's the best solution:

write this in your script tag:

import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;

then if you have

> **Group id="group" resizeMode="scale"**
>   and a **s:Button id="myButton"** inside it

in order to get the myButton width for example, just compute **group.$scaleX * myButton.width**
Hope this will work.

all the best, 
blz

Comment: thanks for your reply, but my current implementation doesnt allow me to expect a parent (s:Group) there, it only expect his target (child) and takes its width,height. Is there anyother way? Thanks again

Comment: @Max, you wrote: "I have a s:Group with few fixed size components in it..". Can u explain again what you're trying to do? Probably give another code example.

Comment: i have changed my implementation, though i was actually trying to display a tooltip over these sub components based on their sizes (after scaling up or down).

Answer (score 4):

Try `myComponent.transform.pixelBounds.width`.  That should give you an actual measured width wrt the visible X-Axis.  If you are rotating, but you want the scale along X-Axis wrt the component, see [this post on obtaining the scaling of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304022/as3-getting-the-scale-of-a-matrix-object).