# How to obtain parent scaling without iterating through every parent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

There's got to be a better way to do this than overriding every component's updateDisplayList with..

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    var componentWithScaling:UIComponent = this.parent as UIComponent;
    while(componentWithScaling.scaleX != 1)
    {
       componentWithScaling = componentWithScaling.parent as UIComponent;
    }

    var scaleXThatIWant:Number = componentWithScaling.scaleX;
}
```

I feel like this would be very difficult if I wasn't using just a single top(ish) level scale (note it's not set at the stage level) since multiples would not be equal to 1.

Comment: Why are children scaling parents?  Ascendant parent lifecycle could `measure()` and `updateDisplayList()`.

Comment: They're not... I'm trying to obtain the parent scaling of any given child component. (i.e. if scaleX is 0.5>1>1>1>1(child) I want to get 0.5)

Comment: You can use the concanated transfomr matrix to extract the global scale value. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304022/as3-getting-the-scale-of-a-matrix-object